# Get permission denied for ssh

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys

I followed this link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-shell-executor to install SSH key using shell executor.
all the steps were running fine but at the final step when I tried to log in to the remote server in order to accept the fingerprint
by this script `ssh gitlab-runner@myserver.com`
I receive the following error

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I added the ssh public key in settings >> sshkey
also add it into variables as SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS

I couldnt find what is the issue , could you help me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try a `ssh -Tv gitlab-runner@myserver.com` in order to check which exact key and paths are considered when trying to read the remote server.

That will give you a clue why the connection fails, when you compare those paths with the ones set up when you  inject an SSH key into your build environment by extending your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.